# UITableView Space 3 UITableViewCells across entire device frame evenly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm writing an app that has a view with nested UITableViews. The UITableViews in the cells of the outer UITableView are rotated 90 degrees so that they scroll horizontally. The UITableViewCells in the main UITableView are of the class HorizontalTableViewCell.

```
                    UITableView
--------------------------------------------------    
|                |               |               |
|                |               |               | HorizontalTableView
|       >        |       >       |       >       | (contained inside
|                |               |               | UITableView's 
|                |               |               | UITableViewCell)
--------------------------------------------------
|                |               |               |
|                |               |               |
|       >        |       >       |       >       |   |
|                |               |               |  \ /
|                |               |               |   "
--------------------------------------------------
|                |               |               |
|                |               |               |
|       >        |       >       |       >       |
|                |               |               |
|                |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------
```

When in portrait mode, I have the content spaced evenly by setting the HorizontalTableView's width to the screen width in the `initWithFrame:` method.

I would like to increase the cell padding of the HorizontalTableView's cells such that when the device is rotated to landscape mode, the 3 cells are resized to fit the entire screen, each taking up an equal amount of space.

However, the best I can seem to achieve is a HorizontalTableView of the same portrait width, but centered in the screen by the following bitmask (from HorizontalTableViewCell's implementation file):

```
self.horizontalTableView.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

This produces a large margin on both sides of the HorizontalTableView, effectively centering the cells, but the individual cell padding remains unchanged.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

(Note that if the following bit mask is used, the cells fly out of view "through the top" of the HorizontalTableViewCell and cannot be seen again, even if the device rotates back to portrait mode).

```
self.horizontalTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to create another view for the landscape mode. Throw your data into a holder object, load the new view, and then reload the data from the holder.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of...

I spent a good three hours on this and could not get anything to produce the desired effect. Hopefully it won't come to this, though.

Comment: I actually have an application where I have tableviews inside of tableviewcells. It was WAY too much work to make it rotate, so I just disabled rotation. You may want to try this strategy, unless rotation is completely indispensable for some reason.

Comment: Making it rotate wasn't too difficult, but it doesn't look _AS NICE_ as it could be... I'm ok with leaving it as is if there's no good way to manage the properties of the table cells on rotation, since I don't want to restrict the user's ability to manipulate the app's orientation.

Comment: Wait, are you using custom cells? If you are not, then perhaps you can try making your own cells and setting the autoresizing properties.

Comment: I'm using custom cells for the TableView within the main UITableView's cells, yes.

Comment: Are the UITableViewCells (non-horizontal) subclassed? Because if they are you may want to use their IB autoresizing properties (if you haven't tried that yet)

Comment: They are subclassed, and I have worked with the autoresizing properties, although to no avail (see the autoresizingMasks in the original question).

Comment: That's unfortunate, in your question it seemed like maybe you were just passing autoresizing values to the table. I can understand your confusion, since this seems like it should work.